# Programmatically populating a checkbox in jQuery mobile in the callback

Tags: jquery-mobile, checkbox

[The documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/checkboxes/events.html) says to use:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").bind( "change", function(event, ui) {
```

But I want to know if that's still true over

```
$("input:checkbox]").on('change', function(event, ui) {
```

Also, I'd like to stop the check from appearing and then programmatically have it appear when the callback is run.

The solution probably includes the refresh method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use

```
$(this).removeAttr('checked').checkboxradio('refresh');
```

to turn the checkbox off and then

```
$(this).prop('checked',true).checkboxradio('refresh');
```

to turn it back on.

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function(myEvent, ui) {
    var settings = {};
    settings.data = {};
    settings.data.PersonID = $(this).val();
    settings.data.EvntID = $('#EvntID').val();

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).removeAttr('checked').checkboxradio('refresh');
        settings.data.method = 'check';
        settings.context = this;
        myXHR = $(this).myAjax('Evnt.cfc',settings);
        myXHR.done(function(result) {
            if (!result.MSG) {
                $(this).prop('checked',true).checkboxradio('refresh');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(this).prop('checked',true).checkboxradio('refresh');
        settings.data.method = 'uncheck';
        myXHR = $(this).myAjax('Evnt.cfc',settings);
        myXHR.done(function(result) {
            if (!result.MSG) {
                $(this).removeAttr('checked').checkboxradio('refresh');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: $(this).prop('checked', bool).checkboxradio('refresh'); worked for me. thanx!

Comment: Yes, I think that's the new hotness now. What's the right thing to do now? Should I edit my answer?

Comment: Actually both are working but I preferred the prop solution because, accepting a  boolean, it avoid me an if statement.

Comment: By the way, it's a little off topic but perhaps could help someone... 
I run into some issues trying to make a single js for both mobile and standard html pages. actually in my implementation jQuery mobile cosider my checkboxes as checkboxradio, jQuery UI generic buttons. This is not a problem for checking/unchecking but it do make a difference when refreshing.
My solution was call a refreshing function hardcoded in the specifics pages.